# Pad numbers to specific length in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a column with integer numbers like this: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and I want to create another column with these values padded to length of three like this: `001, 002, 003, 004, 005`.

Is it possible to pad string to length in Google Spreadsheet?

I wasn't being able to find a standard function for this.

Comment: This is not precisely what you have asked for, but achieves a comparable effect and might be a solution for a common task people search for: (1) select the column with the numbers you want padded. (2) Select Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format ... (3) In the dialog enter as many 0 as digits the number string should have, e.g. 000 in your example.

Comment: use \0\00 on custom number format

Answer (score 83):

Recommended way is to use [TEXT() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en).

Quick summary on how you would use it in your case:

```
=TEXT(5,"000")
```

Would output:

```
005
```

Of course you would substitute the literal 5 with a reference to another cell where the source number is.

Comment: Would there be a way of padding with spaces?

Comment: I think just substitude "000" with "   " above

Comment: @Álex : Use `?` instead of `0` for whitespace padding. [Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting%2Ccustom-currency-formatting%2Ccustom-date-formatting) (See table under Custom Number Formatting pulldown.)

Comment: thank you, friend! the `?` has eluded me and will change my life for the better

Answer (score 12):

If you just want display changes you can apply the **custom number format** "000" to the cells.[image]

Select the cells, Click on *Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format...*.

From [Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470):

> A digit in the number. An insignificant 0 will appear in the results.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to expand on how the OP would do this?

Answer (score 5):

## Temporary solution

Here's the temporary workaround that I came up with.

### Working formula

Just use this formula:

```
`=IF(LEN(A2)<3, CONCATENATE(REPT("0", 3-LEN(A2)), A2), A2)`
```

Replace `3` with padding length and `0` with padding character. `A2` is a padding source.

### Explanation

Consider the following spreadsheet:

```
-------------
| A   |  B  |
-------------
| 1   | 001 |
-------------
| 2   | 002 |
-------------
| 31  | 031 |
-------------
| 45  | 045 |
-------------
| 500 | 500 |
-------------
```

We have initial column (A) with integers that we want to pad. The (B) column will contain the special formula to process the data.

#### Concatenate!

First of all we need a way to concatenate value from `A` column with padding string. We can do this with [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123) function:

```
=CONCATENATE("00", A2)
```

#### Repeat!

Right now, padding character `0` is repeated twice in our formula. This is not good. We can use [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134) function to repeat our padding character several times like this:

```
=REPT("0", 2)
```

This formula will repeat `0` two times. Let's combine them:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("0", 2), A2)
```

#### Calculate length!

That's better. But padding length has a constant value in our formula and that is not going to work with numbers greater than 9. We can fix this by calculating length of the padded string (using [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081) function) and subtract it from our target length:

```
=3-LEN(A2)
```

Let's add it to our formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("0", 3-LEN(A2)), A2)
```

However, we will get negative results for values greater than 999 and it will break the [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134) function (number of repetitions can not be negative).

We can easily fix it by adding a condition:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<3, "APPLY REPT", "OUTPUT AS IS")
```

Let's put the final peaces together:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<3, CONCATENATE(REPT("0", 3-LEN(A2)), A2), A2)
```

Comment: Perfect! This is the best answer and it works with non-numeric values ;-D